# Speech recognition on Android trainable for specific grammar/accent?

Tags: android, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I want to develop an Android application that has speech to text features. Is there a program available which will be possible to train (in English) for specific grammar/accent?

Comment: [check this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to train your speech recognition system and improve it's accuracy, you should search for more flexible framework than google's embedded speech recognition.

You can try CMUSphinx, an open source speech recognition toolkit which is flexible offline solution that allows you to specify the grammar and train acoustic model for speech recognition. To learn how to use CMUSphinx for speech recognition see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialandroid

To learn how to adapt the acoustic model for CMUSphinx (usually you don't need that) see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

To learn how to write the grammar see

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutoriallm

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

```
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(
    RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");

    try {
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_SPEECH);
    editSearchEditText.setText("");
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException a) {
    Toast t = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
    "Ops! Your device doesn't support Speech to Text",
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    t.show();
    }
    }
    });


    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

switch (requestCode) {
case RESULT_SPEECH: {
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {

ArrayList<String> text = data
.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
String searchResult = text.get(0);

Toast.makeText(context,searchResult,TOAST>LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
break;
}

}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you, go through them

[How to implement](http://www.jameselsey.co.uk/blogs/techblog/android-how-to-implement-voice-recognition-a-nice-easy-tutorial/)

[Link 2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/SpeechRecognizer.html)

[Link 3](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/package-summary.html)

Comment: Can I train this model? (specifically the one in link 1?)

Comment: with existing, but perhaps you can have your own server where you implement same logic, basically a voice recognization server, its a big area. so for time being no !